# Gradle - Web Module in deployment descriptor

Tags: war, ear, gradle

I am trying to add a web module in an Ear file. I put it in my customized deployment descriptor using webModule(":wars/myweb","/mywebapp"). It is not including the war file in the ear file. It is just adding a entry in the generated application.xml with these details. 
Can you please help in including a web module in ear, using customized deployment descriptor?

My ear task looks like this in  build.gradle

```
ear {
libDirName ''
deploymentDescriptor {
    // custom entries for application.xml:
    //      fileName = "application.xml"  // same as the default value
    version = "1.4"  // same as the default value
    applicationName = "myapp"
    initializeInOrder = true
    displayName = "myear"  // defaults to project.name
    description = "EAR for the basic package"  // defaults to project.description
    webModule(':wars/myweb','/mywebapp')

}
```

}

My settings.xml in the same dir as build.gradle looks like this

```
include "wars/myweb"
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried to add a dependencies and a project in that, it creates and includes war in the ear now. It sets a context root automatically with the war file name, where as I want to set my own context root. Any suggestions?? Ear dependencies looks like this dependencies { deploy project(':wars/myweb'){ version = rootVersion } } inline `code in backticks`,

Comment: Did `webModule(':wars/myweb', '/mywebapp')` not work? What version of gradle are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I use this way to tie war dependencies to the webModules. The warMap provides a connection between the artifact id and the context path:

```
Map warMap = [
    'my-war': 'contextpath',
    'my2-war': 'contextpath2'
}
dependencies {
    warMap.each {
        deploy project(":$it.key")
    }
}
ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        warMap.each {
            webModule(it.key + '-' + project.version + ".war", it.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, it adds two context roots that violates the J2EE 1.4 specification. So the deployment fails. Any help is apprecaited.

Comment: Hmm, what message do you get? This is a cut-down example I probably have ear.deploymentDescriptor.version = '6'

Comment: Message is _A file does not exist for module element having uri myweb_. It is adding one context root with deploy task and another one with webModule in deployment descriptor.

Comment: What is the name of your war file and what does the web.xml say? I'm not sure what you mean "It is adding one context root with deploy task"; which deploy task?

Comment: Name of war file is myweb.war. It is adding one context root with dependencies>>warMap.each>>deploy project() to the the application.xml that is generated, when we run the build.

Comment: I've just helped a colleague that run right into the same problem. The file name argument of the webModule (here: it.key + '-' + project.version + ".war") need to match up directly with the actual file name as put into the war. If you do that, then the ear-plugin will not create additional entries.